# Using RegEx to match dates

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regEx and I need to match the format
Dec. 12, 2013 or Dec 12 2013
so far I have

`((Jan(?:uary)|Feb(?:ruary)|Mar(?:ch)|Apr(?:il)|May|Jun(?:e)|Jul(?:y)|Aug(?:ust)|Sep(?:tember)|Oct(?:ober)|Nov(?:ember)|Dec(?:ember)) [0-9,]{1,2} [0-9]{4})`

How do I get it to optionally accept a period after the month?

Comment: Using [0-9]{1,2} can result in 99. You should change to [0-3][0-9]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `\.?` for optional period:

```
(Jan\.?(?:uary)|...
```

Comment: This will (undesirably) match `Jan.uary`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of each of the non-capturing groups, alternate with `|\.`, to allow for either "Jan." or "January". Also, make said non-capturing groups optional, to allow, eg, "Dec" without a period or "ember". In addition, change the ending pattern to

```
\d{1,2},? \d{4})
```

to allow for one or two digits, followed by an optional comma, followed by year. (Use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` when possible - it's easier to read)

In full:

```
((Jan(?:uary|\.)?|Feb(?:ruary|\.)?|Mar(?:ch|\.)?|Apr(?:il|\.)?|May|Jun(?:e|\.)?|Jul(?:y|\.)?|Aug(?:ust|\.)?|Sep(?:tember|\.)?|Oct(?:ober|\.)?|Nov(?:ember|\.)?|Dec(?:ember|\.)?) \d{1,2},? \d{4})
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/0Zqd9Y/1